# Is $f: S^1 \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ an embedding, submersion, or immersion? Defined via $f(x,y)=y$.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-functions

Let

$$f: S^1 \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$$

be a smooth map given via

$$(x,y) \mapsto y$$

I can't it being surjective as large elements of $\Bbb{R}$ don't get "hit" and it cannot be $1-1$ as $(-1,0),(1,0)$ both map to $0$. My initial thought was its an immersion.

Comment: Have you computed the derivatives?

Comment: Would it just be $1$ @Randall ?

Comment: It depends on the point.

Comment: ah you're right @Randall , sorry I'm new to diff geo im self teaching myself prior to the course starts this year.

Comment: I know if rank $f$ = dim$S^1$ then its an immersion, right? and if it equals dim$\Bbb{R}$ then its a submersion. @Randall where rank is the rank of the derivative map between tan spaces?

Comment: Draw pictures. What does the derivative actually do to tangent vectors to the circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these questions are answered by looking at the differential $Df_{(0,1)}\colon T_{(0,1)}S^1\to T_1\mathbb R$.

Note that since $\dim(S^1)=\dim(\mathbb R)$, the dimension of their tangent spaces match, so a map $S^1\to\mathbb R$ being an immersion is equivalent to it being a submersion.

Comment: thus if the rank of $Df_{(0,1)}$ equals their dimension, its an embedding?

Comment: $Df_{(0,1)}=0$ is neither injective nor surjective, so $f$ is neither an immersion nor a submersion.

Comment: so $f$ is neither then?

Comment: Yes, I'll leave it for you to check that indeed $Df_{(0,1)}=0$. It should follow fairly straightforwardly from definitions.

Comment: is it because $f_{(0,1)}=1$ and derivative of $1$ is $0$?

Comment: No, that is not the reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the chart $\phi : (x,y)\to x$ on the up half of the circle, then $f\circ \phi ^{-1} = \sqrt{1-x^2}$ has its derivative equal zero at 0. What means that $f$ has a critical point on the point $(0,1)$.